# Read text from a file and realloc when needed

Tags: c

I want to read text from a text file line by line and do some processing on these lines. I can do all processing, but I can't do grow memory with malloc-realloc. I gave limited memory first, if my text file's lines characters are in this limit everything is ok. If I use large files like 10,000 chars per line it only reads until my limit. I don't exactly understand how to use `realloc()`. what can i do about this code?

```
 void stat(char* fileptr)
{

  FILE *fp;
  char *linebuffer;
  int line=0;
  int sum=0;
  int max=0;
  int min=0;
  int maxlinelen=512;
  int i=0,j=0;
  int maxlen=512;
  int curlinelen[maxlen];

  linebuffer=(char*) malloc(maxlinelen * sizeof(char));
  if(linebuffer==NULL)
    {
      printf("Error occurred allocating memory for linebuffer");
      exit(1);
    }


  if((fp=fopen(fileptr,"r"))!=NULL)
  {
    while((fgets(linebuffer,maxlinelen,fp))!=NULL)
      {
    if(strlen(linebuffer)==maxlinelen)
      {
        maxlinelen*=2;
        linebuffer=realloc(linebuffer,maxlinelen * sizeof(char));
        if(linebuffer==NULL)
          {
        printf("Error occurred reallocating space for linebuffer");
        exit(1);
          }
      }
    line++;

        sum=sum+strlen(linebuffer);
    curlinelen[i]=strlen(linebuffer);
    i++;

      }
  }
  min=curlinelen[0];
  max=curlinelen[0];
  for(j=0;j<line;j++)
    {
      if(curlinelen[j]<min)
    {
      min=curlinelen[j];
    }
      if(curlinelen[j]>max)
    {
      max=curlinelen[j];
    }
    }


 printf("No. of lines        =%d\n",line);
 printf("Maximum line length =%d\n",max);
 printf("Minimum line length =%d\n",min);       
 printf("Average line length =%8.2f\n",(float)sum/(float)line);

 fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `* sizeof(char)` is unneeded, and typecasting the return of `malloc()` is unwise.

Comment: Rather than `sizeof(char)` I would use `sizeof(*linebuffer)` which has the benefit of automatically becoming bigger if you decide to change the type of linebuffer to a wide character string or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fgets(linebuffer,maxlinelen,fp)
```

reads and stores at most `maxlinelen - 1` characters in `linebuffer` and 0-terminates it. Thus

```
if(strlen(linebuffer)==maxlinelen)
```

is never satisfied, `strlen(linebuffer)` can be at most `maxlinelen - 1`. Change the condition, and you will see that `maxlinelen` increases if the file contains long lines (unless `realloc` fails).

Your current code will however count the partial line read in as an entire line then, and read the next chunk of the line as a new line. To grow the buffer until the entire line fits in, you must continue reading from the file before collecting the line length and incrementing the line count. But we must check whether a full line (including the newline at the end) was read in case `fgets` reads the maximal allowed number of `char`s before enlarging the buffer, or we'd concatenate the following line and count two (or in freak cases even more) lines as one.

```
while((fgets(linebuffer,maxlinelen,fp))!=NULL)
  {
  while((strlen(linebuffer) == maxlinelen-1) && (linebuffer[maxlinelen-2] != '\n'))
  {
    maxlinelen*=2;
    linebuffer=realloc(linebuffer,maxlinelen * sizeof(char));
    if(linebuffer==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error occurred reallocating space for linebuffer");
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(linebuffer + (maxlinelen/2 - 1), maxlinelen/2 + 1, fp);
  }
```

would be a (rather inefficient, due to the `strlen` calls) way to do that.

Comment: You could probably do a little more coding work and avoid repeated use of strlen on potentially large strings by using `fgetc`.  I'm not going to nit pick about it though because that's no fun.

Comment: Thank you Daniel!! but i got still problem. my sample text file (infile) like that;

its correct output; 
No. of lines : 2
Maximum line length : 50001
Minimum line length : 10001 
Average : 30001.00

my prog outputs 
No of lines : 8
Maximum line length :25427
Minimum line length :511
average : 7500,25

i dont understand. whats wrong about it?

Comment: @ccc That's because you increment the line count `line++;` etc. even if the `fgets` didn't read in an entire line. Print out the `curlinelen` array as far as it was filled to see.

Comment: @DanielFischer this file becomes 2 lines. first lines becoming 10001 a's  and second line becoming 50001 b's. but my prog reads 8 lines?? i confused here. and i tried printout curlinelen array i get seg.fault. like that,
......
......
line++;
sum=sum+strlen(linebuffer);
curlinelen[i]=strlen(linebuffer);
printf("%s\n",curlinelen[i]);  //i tried also %c i get ?  ? ? some liek that
i++;

Comment: @ccc First, it reads 511 'a's from the first line, then it reallocs and increments the line count, storing 511 in `curlinelen[0]`. Then it reads the next 1023 'a's from the first line, booking that as the second line and growing the buffer. Then the next 2047 'a's, still from the first line of the file as line 3, etc.

Comment: @DanielFischer  I'm still working on it but i wanna ask question. if my text file more than 511 lines? whats gonna happen? how can i grow memory for lines?

Comment: @Wug my code is totally wrong? its working without malloc, but i have to use realloc b'cuz some files really big. what u think?

Comment: @DanielFischer  i got it !!. but still i have problem about realloc about lines.  do u have any idea about how can i grow line's realloc?

Comment: @ccc If you have a file with more than 512 lines, you'd need to make `curlinelen` a `malloc`ed block too and `realloc` that when there are more lines.

Comment: @ccc: my comment was feedback on Dan's answer, not your question.  I was merely remarking that some file read functions are kind enough to return the number of characters they read, which would eliminate the expensive `strlen` calls.

Comment: What happens if a line is exactly `maxlinelen-1` long?  Won't this concatenate the next line (and the next, etc, given pathological line lengths). Shouldn't you check for the end of line at the end of the string?

Comment: @pat If it's exactly that, including the trailing `\n`, it'll indeed concatenate the next line. You're right, we need to check for the newline. Thanks.