# fseek and fread C programming

Tags: c, fread, fseek

**EDIT: Thanks everyone for the quick answers. :)**

Ok i am new in *C* and i am able to open a file and set to a certain position in the file and read a chunk of data and write it to another file using this code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, unsigned char *argv[])

  {

      FILE* in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
      FILE* out = fopen("test.bin", "wb");

      unsigned char buffer[0x200];

      fseek(in, 0x8F00, SEEK_SET);
      fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, in);   
      fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, out);
  };
```

**But** i am kind of versed in *perl* and i can easily seek to any position in the file and read a chunk of data like this:

```
seek ( $file, 0x8F00, 0);
read ( $file, $buffer, 0x200);
```

As you can see i dont have to pre-declare my buffer size in *perl*, i can specify buffer in the read function itself. Is there anyway at all i can use buffer in *C* without having to predeclare it like in *perl*?

Comment: All used variables in C must be declared and defined.

Comment: think on this - perl is written in C

Comment: i know and i use perl constantly, i have chosen to migrate to C because what i want to do /now/ requires C programming, but yes, perl is very fast, and fast to program with too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in C you need to provide a buffer size upfront, and pass that buffer to the `fread` function.

You do not need to specify a constant buffer size, though: the size of `0x200` in your case could be calculated at run-time, for example, by examining the size of the file that you are reading.

Note, however, that when your program selects the size of the buffer dynamically, you should place the buffer in the dynamic memory area, rather than leaving it in the automatic area (i.e. on the stack). This lets you avoid stack overflows when the file is too large, because the restrictions on the automatic memory are usually a lot more severe than the restrictions on the dynamic memory.

You could also write code that populates the buffer incrementally, expanding it as needed using `realloc`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13346904/335858) for an example of expanding the read buffer dynamically.

Comment: well i am reading a file, and in this file i know the size of the chunks ect, i was just wondering if there was a way to declare my buffer like fread(buffer, 0x200, 1, out);<br> but looks like its not possible ;(

Comment: @james28909 The fact that the standard C library does not have the function that you are looking for shouldn't prevent you from writing such function yourself. The only thing you should keep in mind is that if you go that route, you must allocate the buffer dynamically with `malloc`, because functions cannot return local arrays.

Comment: well i have this file with alot of data i need to extract, i think what im going to do is just code it like in my op first and get used to everything so it will make more sense to me in the long run, then i will go back and start rewriting and trying new stuffs :P thanks for the link and the clear answer

Comment: just fyi, i was able to sit down today and finally get back to this. i was able to do it, but not in the approach i was taking. i had to change it up a little bit, but i have it working flawless now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway at all I can use buffer in C without having to predeclare it like in perl?

No.

*C* is a lower-level language than *Perl* and does not have magic self-resizing strings, buffers, or arrays. Your options are to allocate a huge buffer that's bigger than you anticipate ever needing, or read your file incrementally into a buffer that you resize as needed.

Answer (score 1):

no, at least not using standard library.

This is because by default C does not handle automatically dinamic memory, as this kind of control is left to the user.

you can easly go to the end of the file, read how many byte there are, then jump to your location, create a buffer of size `file_size - file_location` and do your rest-of-file reading

```
fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell(fp);
```