# Re: Reading a line and using realloc in C

Tags: c, file, fgets, realloc

So I browsed some of the same questions and found a working answer. I was just wondering if someone can explain to me the last line of the code from this answer:

[Read text from a file and realloc when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346904/read-text-from-a-file-and-realloc-when-needed/13346945#13346945)

```
fgets(linebuffer + (maxlinelen/2 - 1), maxlinelen/2 + 1, fp); //this line
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Search for "c pointer arithmetic".

Comment: BTW, there are simpler ways to implement a read-and-realloc loop, e.g. [like this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/137864).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writer is trying to read into the second half of the array. In order to do that, the base address must be higher. Hence the first argument `linebuffer + (maxlinelen/2 - 1)`. It's taking the base address of the array, and adding half the array's length to it.

But since the array is half as long, the writer halves the size of the array. Hence the second argument, `maxlinelen/2 + 1`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When it double the capacity first half of the `linebuffer` is fill, the other half is empty. Because of that, it is writing data starting from middle of the `linebuffer`. Thus he do not overwrite to first half of the `linebuffer`